# Trying to upload a file through jQuery .post() - file input not showing up on back end (using codeigniter)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, upload

First of all I'd like to ask that you don't suggest I turn to a jQuery plugin to solve my issue. I'm just not willing to make my app work with a plugin (and it prevents me from learning!)

I have a form with a bunch of fields that I'm passing to my backend via the use of jQuery's `$.post()` This is what I have as my jQuery function:

```
 $.post(
    "/item/edit",
    $("#form").serialize(),
    function(responseJSON) {
        console.log(responseJSON);
    },
    "html"
);
```

This is how I opened my form:

```
<form action="http://localhost/item/edit" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This was auto generated by codeigniter's `form_open()` method (hence why action="" has a value. Though this shouldn't matter because I don't have a submit button at the end of the form)

Within my `#form` I have this as my file input: `<input type="file" name="pImage" />`

When the appropriate button is hit and the `$.post()` method is called, I have my backend just print the variables like so: `print_r($_POST)` and within the printed variables the 'pImage' element is missing. I thought that maybe files wouldn't come up as an element in the array so I went ahead and just tried to upload the file using this codeigniter function: `$this->upload->do_upload('pImage');` and I get an error: "You did not select a file to upload."

Any idea as to how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: You can't send a file through ajax, and, files aren't available in post date, they're available in `$_FILES` data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post an image using AJAX, i had to find out here as well [PHP jQuery .ajax() file upload server side understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481682/php-jquery-ajax-file-upload-server-side-understanding)

Your best bet is to mimic an ajax call using a hidden iframe, the form has to have enctype set to multipart/formdata

Answer (score 0):

Files wont be sent to server side using AJAX
One of the best and simplest JQuery Ajax uploaders  from [PHP LETTER](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/)

all you need is include js in your header normally and Jquery code will be like below

> $.ajaxFileUpload({
>
> ```
>     url:'http://localhost/speedncruise/index.php/snc/upload/do_upload',
>
>     secureuri:false,
>     fileElementId:'file_upload',
>     dataType: 'json',
>     data    : {
>         'user_email' : $('#email').val()
>     },
>     success: function (data, status) {
>       //  alert(status);
>        // $('#avatar_img').attr('src','data');
>        
>     }
>     ,
>     error: function (data, status, e) {
>         console.log(e);
>     }
> });
> ```

wish this can help you

Answer (score 0):

I can't do this with codeigniter and Ajax, I pass the image to base64 and in the controller I convert into a file again

```
//the input file type
<input id="imagen" name="imagen" class="tooltip" type="file" value="<?php if(isset($imagen)) echo $imagen; ?>">

//the js
$(document).on('change', '#imagen', function(event) {
  readImage(this);
});

function readImage(input) {
    var resultado='';
    if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
            //console.log(e.target.result);
            subirImagen(e.target.result);
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( input.files[0] );
    }
}

function subirImagen(base64){
    console.log('inicia subir imagen');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'controller/sube_imagen',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            imagen: base64,
        }
    })
    .done(function(d) {
        console.log(d);
    })
    .fail(function(f) {
        console.log(f);
    })
    .always(function(a) {
        console.log("complete");
    });
}

//and the part of de controller
public function sube_imagen(){
    $imagen=$this->input->post('imagen');
    list($extension,$imagen)=explode(';',$imagen);
    list(,$extension)=explode('/', $extension);
    list(,$imagen)=explode(',', $imagen);
    $imagen = base64_decode($imagen);
    $archivo='archivo.'.$extension;
    file_put_contents('imagenes/'.$archivo, $imagen);
    chmod('imagenes/'.$archivo, 0777); //I use Linux and the permissions are another theme
    echo $archivo; //or you can make another thing
}
```

ps.: sorry for my english n_nU