# Ajax not sending data without reload

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, post

The follwing ajax script isn't sending data to php, the page just reloads & form input values are passed onto the url.

Script

```
<script>
  $("#addProducts").submit(function(event) {
     var str = $("addProducts").serialize();
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "subAddProduct.php",
        data:str
     })
  });
</script>
```

HTML Form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addProducts">
...
</form>
```

Comment: check manual in jquery for ajax

Comment: `.submit()` submits the form. Use `.click()`instead. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: Tried putting the `event.preventDefault()` above your `str` variable declaration?

Comment: Change the type of your submit button from 'submit' to 'button' and then call the function on "onclick" event

Comment: Also, your form serialisation is incorrect... should be `var str = $("#addProducts").serialize();` - missing the `#` from the form ID

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481682/php-jquery-ajax-file-upload-server-side-understanding

Answer (score 2):

There's already a problem in your code: `$("addProducts").serialize();` should be `$("#addProducts").serialize();`.

I just ran some tests. The problem is because you try to bind your function before your document is ready. Please replace your code by the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function(event) {
         var str = $("#form1").serialize();
         event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: str
        });
    });
});
```

About what Zeeshan Bilal and pvorb said, I'm afraid it's false. `submit()` is the right function to use (see [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)).

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#addProducts").click(function(event) {
    var str = $("#addProducts").serialize();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "subAddProduct.php",
        data:str
    });
});
```

Comment: if u use ajax serialize for file upload this will not work .And u have type error in  $("#addProducts") here.U missed #

Comment: no change, the input values are just going up with url & the page reloads every time

Comment: how can i upload files using this script

Comment: don't use submit ever.use click event

Comment: Here is a example of what you is talking about. http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are trying to bind your function when document is not ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#addProducts").submit(function(event) {
 var str = $("addProducts").serialize();
 event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "subAddProduct.php",
 data:str
   })});
```

});

Comment: don't copy and paste. what this $("addProducts")

Comment: $("addProducts") should be $("#addProducts")

Answer (score 1):

Its not ajax  issue, actually you are using `$("#addProducts").submit` that send a page submit request and cause page reload. Use click instead of submit.

The another mistake `$("addProducts").serialize()`, add # for id selector. Below is the sample code:

```
$("#addProducts").click(function(event) {
    var str = $("#addProducts").serialize();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "subAddProduct.php",
        data:str
    });
});
```

Comment: serialization approach.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your JS as below

```
<script>
$("#addProducts").click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "subAddProduct.php",
        dataType : 'json', //data type can be any type like json, html etc.
        data:'str='+str
        success : function(data) {
            //perform your success process here
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I have not tested the above code, but it should work, as i use same codes for my ajax features.

Also check jquery docs for $.ajax  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  $("#addProducts").submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var str = $("#addProducts").serialize();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "subAddProduct.php",
        data:str
     })
  });
</script>
```

HTML Form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addProducts" action="">
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you should modify your code in this way:

```
<script>
$("#addProducts").submit(function(event) {
  var str = $("#addProducts").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "subAddProduct.php",
    data:str,
    success: function(data){
      //perform your success process here
      return false;
    }
  })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Setting the Ajax async property to false as shown below

```
<script>
  $("#addProducts").submit(function(event) {
     var str = $("addProducts").serialize();
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
        async:false
        type: "POST",
        url: "subAddProduct.php",
        data:str
     })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing the hashtag when you serialize... your code is having jQuery look for an element called "addProducts" not an element with an id of "addProducts" change this line

```
var str = $("addProducts").serialize();
```

to this line

```
var str = $("#addProducts").serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $("#addProducts").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var str = $("#addProducts").serialize();
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "subAddProduct.php",
      data:str
   })
    });
    return false;
</script>
```

You need to preventDefault, which stops the form being submitted normally, causing the page to reload. You then need to return false after because Firefox doesn't like preventDefault :P

Comment: did u even know ajax?   why both  event.preventDefault(); and return false; .those doing same thing

Comment: Well considering preventDefault isn't Ajax, you clearly have no idea! It's called cross browser testing, you may want to do some research.

Comment: $("addProducts") should be $("#addProducts")